FabricJS: TextBox poorly rendered when overloading _renderBackground method
I want to add a box around a Fabric JS TextBox object. 
But strange behavior (two vertical lines) occurs when I try to expand and collapse the TextBox along the horizontal axis.
Here is the code and the output :


fabric.CustomTextbox = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Textbox, {
    type: 'CustomTextbox',

    initialize: function(text, options) {
        options || (options = {});
        this.callSuper('initialize', text, options);
        this.bgpad = options.bgpad || 10;

    },

    _renderBackground: function(ctx) {
        const w = this.width + this.bgpad * 2,
          h = this.height + this.bgpad * 2,
          x = -this.width / 2 - this.bgpad,
          y = -this.height / 2 - this.bgpad;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = this.backgroundColor;
        ctx.roundRect(x, y, w, h, 10);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    },
});

let text =  new fabric.CustomTextbox('  ...  ', {
                fontSize: 14,
        fontWeight: 600,
        left: 100,
        top: 50,
        width: 100,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
     });
     
let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('mycanvas', { width: 1000, height: 1000});
canvas.add(text);
canvas.renderAll();
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>



See the output textbox:

